# How to correctly implement a polymorphic functional Tree data structure in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics, tree, polymorphism, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement a polymorphic tree:

```
trait Tree[A]

case object Void extends Tree[A]  // does not compile
case class Node[A](left: Tree[A], key: A, right: Tree[A]) extends Tree[A]
```

Surely I can change `Void` from an object to a class, or I can have it extend `Tree[Any]`, but I was wondering what would be the textbook implementation of this  `Tree` in Scala. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Either you make `Tree` covariant

```
trait Tree[+A]
case object Void extends Tree[Nothing]
```

(then `Void` is a subtype of `Tree[A]` for any `A`)

- or you keep `Tree` invariant and then make `Void` a class

```
trait Tree[A]
case class Void[A]() extends Tree[A]
```

Objects (and values generally) can't be polymorphic in Scala (and JVM).

Making `Void` extend `Tree[Any]` is incorrect. Then `Void` isn't a subtype of `Tree[A]`.

In principle, if you can perform all calculations at compile time, then you can lift your algebraic data type to the type level making `Tree` a type class

```
trait Tree[A, T]

case object Void
type Void = Void.type
case class Node[A, L, R](left: L, key: A, right: R)

implicit def voidTree[A]: Tree[A, Void] = new Tree[A, Void] {}
implicit def nodeTree[A, L, R](implicit
  leftTree: Tree[A, L],
  rightTree: Tree[A, R]
): Tree[A, Node[A, L, R]] = new Tree[A, Node[A, L, R]] {}
```